Which account to install Node under for PHP Shell_exec?
I'm using Amazon Linux 2023 with Apache/PHP and I'd like to shell_exec to node.js. How do I install node.js to make it available to PHP? PHP runs under apache account? Do you install node under the apache account?  I understand it's not advisable to install node.js under root.
